# How can I model this twisted arrangement of cubes?

Tags: modeling

How can I model this handle?

[image]

I'm stuck on the cubes. I've tried an array modified + simple deform twist, but that's not quite right:

[image]

I think the cubes need to be *arranged along the curve* and *only slightly skewed*.

Comment: If you really want to follow your irregular reference closely, just manually create and align the cubes, it's only about 20 objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

**Particles or Manual Edit**

Consider using a Particle System on a helix strip mesh created by Simple Deform Twist modifier.  Particles would be a group of objects which are cubes with random variation of shape.  Use Initial Orientation Normal with some small Random Value as depicted above.  No Array Modifier.

If you have just a few cubes you could
Press the [Convert] button to make duplicates real
and give each a rotation by hand.

The imperfect cubes are in a group and you can see a rotation of one in edit mode.

You may wish to state if you want to keep the varIations in cube shape and rotation.

[image]

[image]

The image above show 2 examples of orientation.

Full Coverage.  Placing a single particle on each face in the Helix Mesh.

[image]

[Emission Number] = (face count + 1). Goal 1 particle per face. Close to meeting goal. Result is 2 particles in same position on top. I have never investigated if this is declared a defect. (I have never investigated fully.) If you are going to [Convert make real] this problem may lessen, since you can delete. [Particles/Face=1].  A Hidden Portion of curve may be a bearable near solution.  You can see the two different colored particles on top.  When you increment and decrement Emission Number you can see this (interesting) situation.

Comment: I copied your particle settings - any idea why I can't get full coverage over my faces? https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSpPS.png  - One face gets a doubled object, and another is missing.

Comment: Please see edits.

Comment: Thanks. And I think you're right - I'll just make the particles real and delete the extra cube.